# Can't log in after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: upgrade, login-screen, 17.04

Today I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04. I get to the login page and type my password correctly, then the sign in message disappears, it stays for a few seconds, then returns and asks me to type the password again.

I am sure I am entering the password correctly since when I tried entering a wrong password, the computer displayed "Wrong password. Try again."

Answer (score 1):

Like Dolan said check the caps lock. What you have is likely a very common error, probably the most common on askubuntu. This command has gotten me past that same error on a fresh install with 3 different computers and is harmless if it does not work (open the tty1 bash before login with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and enter your login and password, **then** input this command):

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This will configure any pending packages which you might need in this case to get past the login screen. I've had to enter that same code at the tty1 on all of my fresh Ubuntu installs before I could login. Then go ahead and do

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

to get you to the login screen again.

Comment: If you know that a question has been asked before, please flag the new question as a duplicate of the [original question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop), and don't post an answer on the new question. This helps keep all the info together on the original question. Thanks! :)

Comment: The answer provided in that thread is incorrect. My two step method is much more short and to the point, and gets the job done just as well... I have never tested the answer in that thread whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to clarify. You should post this answer on the original question, instead of the duplicate question.

Comment: It shows over 30 answers in that thread, all which will accomplish the same thing as what I just said. At this rate I might as well delete the post. But everyone makes it too complicated. At most we're dealing with a typical 3 step `sudo apt purge nvidia-*` reboot, open tty1 then `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo service lightdm restart` . It seems to me the community associates longer codes with being better or more effective,  a perfect example being that thread right there.